Dropping nested struct field from parquet file and updating schema using pyspark
I am new to python and pyspark, so need your help in understanding and resolving this problem. I have some parquet log files with the following schema:
|-- metadata
...
|-- request
...
|-- response: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- response_timestamp: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- response_status_code: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- results: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- filters: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- price: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- min: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- max: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- keywords: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- sort_by: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- search_sort_type: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- sort_ascending: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- test_filters: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- integer1: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- min: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- max: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- double1: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- double1: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- double2: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- double2: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- integer2: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- integer2: integer (nullable = true)

I created the 'test_filters' object incorrectly in the schema and some of the parquet files got corrupted, and querying through hive broke.
I corrected the schema since, to fix subsequent logs, but I am now trying to clean up the corrupted files by deleting the test_filters object (the error was that the double1 field should have been integer typs, and after correction, some of the data has this field as double and the rest of the data has it as integer).
How can I remove the test_filters object from nested results array (or change double1 to integer type), and update the parquet schema? Please advise.
I tried loading the parquet files using pyspark, filtering out all rows where none of the results have test_filters:
filtered_result = df.filter(~expr("exists(response.results, x -> x.filters.test_filters is not null)"))

and then creating another dataframe with updated schema (with no test_filters):
df_with_schema = spark.createDataFrame(filtered_result.rdd, schema)

But when I try to write df_with_schema back to parquet files, I get the error:
field filters in element in array field results in field response: Length of object (4) does not match with length of fields (3)

I also tried to write filtered_result directly to parquet files, without updating the schema and creating a new dataframe. But then the hive queries still fail due to schema mismatch.
